# how to include a .jar file with Ant build.xml for Android project

Tags: android, ant

I am developing my first Android app, and *not* using Eclipse. I'm trying to follow the instructions [here](http://developer.samsung.com/s-pen-sdk/technical-docs/S-Pen-SDK-2-2-5-Tutorial), which is written for developing in Eclipse, although I'm using Emacs with Ant's `build.xml`. How would you do the following:

> 1. In Eclipse, add the .jar file to the build path.

with the Ant `build.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

You want to add it to your class path for your `javac` task:

If you have something like this then you would just add it to the same folder with the rest of your jars

```
<path id="master-classpath">
  <fileset dir="lib">
    <include name="*.jar"/>
  </fileset>
</path>
<javac destdir="build">
  <src path="src"/>
   <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
</javac>
```